# Why can't I download apps from the Android Marketplace?

Tags: google-play-store, downloading

I just bought an HTC Desire S and cannot download apps from the Android Marketplace. I tried to download Skype and it stalled saying "Starting To Download" - nothing happened. Then I tried downloading another app and then it said that app will be soon downloaded, but nothing happened.

Comment: Does this happen regardless of whether you are using 3G or WiFi? If you are using a WiFi connection, it may be getting blocked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i found the problem. I turned option off that lets use 3rd party apps internet connection as was recommended on one blog on power plan optimization on Android.

Comment: The thing is, with that off you should ONLY be able to get apps from the Market.

Comment: Yeah, sounds like that even if this works it's still a bug in your operating system. If you don't want to upgrade to a custom ROM, I'd suggest looking for any official updates available from HTC for your device.

Answer (score 2):

Try clearing the cache and data of the Market application.